# create a temp image file for upload

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3, html5-canvas, temporary-files

I have created a HTML5 image uploader using canvas.
I have the image data using

```
Canvas.toDataURL();
```

which is in the form

```
data:image/png;base64,<base64image string>
```

I sent the above data to php which will be used to upload the image to amazon server.

I normally pass the return value of

```
file_get_contents(path_to_file_to_upload);
```

to the amazon sdk and the work gets done.
Now how do i have the base64 image data converted into `file_get_contents` type data to upload the file.

I am not allowed to create a file in the server.Is there any way of creating a temp image and get the `file_get_contents` data from that temp file??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the return value of base64_decode() instead of file_get_contents to the AWS SDK.  file_get_contents loads a file into a string, base64_decode loads a base64 string and returns a string. Since you have a base64 string and not a file, you would call base64_decode.